# Azure Function error for REST Api using Table Storage

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

Hi I am trying out simple Azure Function with REST Api. 
My env is MSVC 2019 and created a simple mmApi Fucntion app

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using AzureFuncApp.Model;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;

namespace AzureFuncApp
{
    public static class mmApi
    {
        //static List<Board> boards = new List<Board>();

        [FunctionName("CreateBoard")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> CreateBoard(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "board")] HttpRequest req,
            [Table("boards", Connection ="AzureWebJobsStorage")] IAsyncCollector<BoardTableEntity> boardTable,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("Creating a new board.");

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            var input = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BoardCreateModel>(requestBody);
            var board = new Board() { PlayerCount = input.PlayerCount };
            board.Players.Add(input.Player);
            await boardTable.AddAsync(board.ToTableEntity());
            return new OkObjectResult(board);
        }
```

It is this line that I have added to Table Storage 
**[Table("boards", Connection ="AzureWebJobsStorage")] IAsyncCollector**

Is throwing the below error

> Function (AzureFuncAppmmApi/CreateBoard) Error:
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'CreateBoard'.
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind parameter 'boardTable' to
>   type IAsyncCollector`1. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by
>   the binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage,
>   ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration
>   method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g.
>   builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(),
>   builder.AddTimers(), etc.).

What I am not following is where do I register **builder.AddAzureStorage()** when I don't have the startup file in my project.

Attached is my project details, any help and pointer is appriciated

[image]

Comment: The static list storage //static List<Board> boards = new List<Board>(); just works fine

Comment: I would try binding to CloudTable instead of IAsyncCollector<> to see whether that works. Also the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage version that works in my projects is 3.0.5. Can you try whether downgrading to that works?

Comment: Also try removing nuget references to Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs and Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core. From my experience referencing extra packages caused many troubles.

Comment: [12/14/2019 10:19:24 PM] The 'GetBoards' function is in error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'GetBoards'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind parameter 'boardTable' to type CloudTable. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).   I do have a GET api using Cloud I still get the error

Comment: I also removed Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs and Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core, still no luck

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions updates to v3.0.2, manually added the below refrences in the csprog file and it works fine. @tubakaya your suggestion helped

````
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.23" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="3.0.1" />   </ItemGroup>```
````

Comment: Good to hear the issue is fixed. Although I find the fragile nature of these references quite frustrating. Documentation is usually not clear about which version of the sdk goes together with which extension package versions.

Comment: Btw if you could upvote my comment which helped, I would appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: I did, since 1.0* to 3.0* each libraries r differently rolled out hence the issues

Comment: this fixes the issue but then deployment stops for me with "publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details"